# Why this Firebase database trigger not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm planning to write a Firebase database trigger. My use case is very simple. Whenever Facebook messenger webhook called database gets updated with user text message and using the Firebase database trigger to get the message from AI and return back to messenger.

Right now my Firebase database trigger is not working. Even though my test cases are all passed.

```
myapp
|_ messages
   |__ 432423423423
     |__ 32432432432423
        |__ owrijrw8hy2487hf34
          |_ recipient: "45354353"
          |_ sender: "422342342"
          |_ text: "this is text"
```

Now I want to perform sending message back to user using firebase database trigger.

```
// Realtime Database triggers
exports.facebookMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pageID}/{userID}')
  .onCreate(event => {
    console.log(event)
    return;
  })
```

/test.js

```
describe('Database /messages/{pageID}/{userID}', () => {
    it('Should trigger when the message write it t', () => {

      pushParam = {
        text:  'Hello',
        sender: 'USER_ID',
        recipient: 'PAGE_ID',
        timestamp: 1458692752478
      }

      // Firebase database fake event
      const fakeEvent = {
        // DeltaSnapshot(app: firebase.app.App, adminApp: firebase.app.App, data: any, delta: any, path?: string);
        data: new functions.database.DeltaSnapshot(null, null, null, pushParam),
        params: {
          pageID: 'PAGE_ID',
          userID: 'USER_ID'
        }
      }

      // Stub data reference
      refParam = '/messages/'
      childPageParam = 'PAGE_ID'
      childUserParam = 'USER_ID'

      // Stubs are objects that fake and/or record function calls.
      // These are excellent for verifying that functions have been called and to validate the
      // parameters passed to those functions.
      const refStub = sinon.stub()
      const childPageStub = sinon.stub()
      const childUserStub = sinon.stub()
      const pushStub = sinon.stub()

      Object.defineProperty(fakeEvent.data, 'ref', {get: refStub})
      refStub.returns({parent: {child: childPageStub}})
      childPageStub.returns({parent: {child: childUserStub}})
      childUserStub.returns({push: pushStub})
      pushStub.withArgs(pushParam).returns(true)

      return assert.eventually.equal(fiobotFunctions.facebookMessage(fakeEvent), undefined);
```

In console I don't see any logs from facebookMessage what should I do now?

Comment: looks like rather sophisticated JavaScript to me. Respectfully, you might want to start with basics.

Comment: I'm learning Ron even though this is the first project I'm using fully firebase and completely no to python.  :)

Comment: Keep at it Rob! You can do it.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks correct to me except for the missing ';' after the `console.log()`

```
// Realtime Database triggers
exports.facebookMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pageID}/{userID}')
  .onCreate(event => {
    console.log(event)
    return;
  })
```

However, you state

> In console I don't see any logs from facebookMessage what should I do
>   now?

Something is wrong with your function. You should have something in the log. I'd also add a `console.log("Test");` to your facebookMessage function just to be sure. If you don't see anything in the logs then your functions is not uploaded correctly or you're not listening at the correct location.

You can test the function without all that Javascript. Just manually write something to the database under `/messages/{pageID}/{userID}` if the log of test doesn't appear I'd check to make sure everything is uploaded correctly.

Comment: Is that a thing ';' :) Thanks for your help. I tested with manual update and it's worked but I think 9i2 pointed out correct problem. Trying to solve now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is missing key in your reference ..

```
myapp
|_ messages // /messages
   |__ 432423423423 // {pageID}
     |__ 32432432432423 // ??
        |__ owrijrw8hy2487hf34 // {userID}
          |_ recipient: "45354353"
          |_ sender: "422342342"
          |_ text: "this is text"
```

Comment: Nooo `32432432432423` is the userID and I don't know about this thing `owrijrw8hy2487hf34` Look like somehow firebase database generated key ah ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to add another params to get the correct value.

```
exports.facebookMessage = functions.database
  .ref('/messages/{pageID}/{userID}/{messageKey}')
```